# How is parser rule precedence chosen with left recursion and a greedy '?' operator?

Tags: antlr4

Taking an (almost) textbook example, where we expect multiplication to have precedence over addition, but also include an optional part to match.

```
expr : expr '*' expr  ('ALSO')?
     | expr '+' expr
     | INT
     ;

INT: [0-9]+;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

When trying out the grammar with `3 * 4 + 2` we get an unexpected tree that looks like

```
                  expr:1
               /    |   \
            expr:1  *   expr:2
              |         /  |  \
              3    expr:1  +  expr:1
                     |           |
                     4           2
```

However, when use `3 + 4 * 2` we get what I might expect

```
                  expr:1
               /    |   \
            expr:1  +   expr:2
              |         /  |  \
              3    expr:1  *  expr:1
                     |           |
                     4           2
```

Also, if you switch the optional token to the second line, we get the expected tree every time.

```
expr : expr '*' expr
     | expr '+' expr ('ALSO')?
     | INT
     ;
```

I also tried this using the non-greedy operator `??`, and defining lexer tokens so we don't have to worry about oddities around ordering due to implicit tokens.

What would explain this ordering?

Comment: For those reading this Q&A, the issue is reported here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2525

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug. You can report it here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues (if it's not already reported... I did not check)

It seems a workaround would be to include an extra alternative that does not contain the `ALSO` token:

```
expr : expr '*' expr 'ALSO'
     | expr '*' expr
     | expr '+' expr
     | INT
     ;
```

which produces the expected parse trees for both `3 * 4 + 2` and `3 + 4 * 2`.

Comment: Bart, I was crawling through the golden `parsing` badge holders - could you have a look [at my question with an open bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405055/nodevisitor-class-for-peg-parser-in-python/55445187#55445187) ?